# How do you turn an Azure Website on and off on a schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a line of business app that I want to deploy to Windows Azure. The app is only needed during office ours so to save on costs I want to turn the Azure Website on and off outside of business hours.

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Azure Automation (currently in preview).  To do this,

Create a Runbook to Start the website.  For example,

```
workflow StartContosoWebsite
{
    $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "rick@cloudalloc.com"

    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred

    InlineScript {

        Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "MCT"

        Start-AzureWebsite -Name "contoso-web"  
    }
}
```

Create a Runbook to Stop the website.  For example,

```
workflow StopContosoWebsite
{
    $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "rick@cloudalloc.com"

    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred

    InlineScript {

        Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "MCT"

        Stop-AzureWebsite -Name "contoso-web"  
    }
}
```

Create an **Asset** in your automation account for the credentials you use in your runbooks to start and stop the web site.  For example,

[image]

Then, for each runbook, define the schedule you want it to run on. For your scenario, you would want to define a **Daily** schedule to run **every 7 days**.  Using the example above, the StartContosoWebsite would run on Monday morning at some time you specify.  The StopContosoWebsite would run on Friday eventing at some time you specify.