# Azure Runbook: The subscription named 'xxx' cannot be found

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I'm trying to compose a Azure Runbook for starting an Azure Website but keep getting the following two errors

> Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription named
>   'vslaazuresubscription' cannot be found. Use Set-AzureSubscription to
>   initialize the subscription data.
>
> Start-AzureWebsite : No current subscription has been designated. Use
>   Select-AzureSubscription -Current   to set the
>   current subscription.

My Runbook is as follows

[image]

My Assets are as follows

[image]

I was trying to follow the SO Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929339/how-do-you-turn-an-azure-website-on-and-off-on-a-schedule) to no avail. I have checked that

1. I have a subscription by that name
2. The admin@vslaactivedirectory.onmicrosoft.com exists in active directory configured for the subscription.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "vslaazuresubscription" is the name of your Azure subscription, and that admin@vslaactivedirectory.onmicrosoft.com is configured as an admin of the vslaazuresubscription subscription?

If you run Get-AzureSubscription after Add-AzureAccount, does it output vslaazuresubscription as one of the available subscriptions?